# Client cannot display report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I developed a desktop application with Visual Studio 2010 and Crystal Reports 13_0_4. I generated the setup for my application, and the application runs but the crystal report is not working.

When I install Crystal Reports manually, I get an error stating

> You must install Visual Studio before installing Crystal Reports

I don't want to install Visual Studio for the client. Otherwise they can open the framework and do the coding for my application. How can I otherwise allow them to view the report?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install manually the crystal report. Just add it like a prerequisite in your setup project, then it will download automatically.

Comment: prerequisite means?

Comment: right click on setup project > properties > prerequisites (button) > add SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine for .NET Framework.